# HTML form validation on click of submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to create a HTML form and on my submit button, it must validate if all the fields are filled and then it must append the details to the table displayed below. But while validating the form, i am not able to get why it is adding data to table even if all the details are filled correctly

Below is code in use :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Assignment</title>
    <style>
     table{
       width: 100%;
       margin: 25px 0;
       border-collapse: collapse;
     }
     table, th, td{
       border: 1px solid #6C220B;
     }
     table th, table td{
       padding: 8px;
       text-align: left;
     }
  </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Assignment on Javascript and Jquery:</h1>
                    <h2>Details form :</h2>
                    <form action="#" method="post" name="form">
                        <div class="form-group" required>
                            <label for="First Name">First Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fn" placeholder="Enter your first name" name="firstname" required="" >
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Last Name">Last Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sn" placeholder="Enter your last name" name="lastname" required="" >
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="Date of birth">Date of birth:</label>
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dob" placeholder="Enter your date of birth" name="dateofbirth" required="" >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="em" placeholder="Enter your email id" name="email" required="" >
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="Phone Number">Phone Number:</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phn" placeholder="Enter your phone number" name="phonenumber" required="" >
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="submit" class="row" value="Click to Add Row">
                                            </form>
                                            <br>
                                                <h2>The table of data :</h2>
                                                <table class="table">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>Firstname</th>
                                                            <th>Lastname</th>
                                                            <th>Date of birth</th>
                                                            <th>Email</th>
                                                            <th>Phone Number</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>Durai</td>
                                                            <td>Saravanan</td>
                                                            <td>16/01/1996</td>
                                                            <td>durairaj1696@gmail.com</td>
                                                            <td>9789879736</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
                                            <script>
     function validateForm() {
            var isValid = true;
        $('.form-group').each(function() {
           if ( $(this).val() === '' )
             isValid = false;
            });
      return isValid;
      }

     $(document).ready(function(){

         $(".row").click(function(){

             var firstname = $("#fn").val();

             var lastname = $("#sn").val();

             var dob = $("#dob").val();

             var email = $("#em").val();

             var phonenumber = $("#phn").val();

             var markup = "
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>" + firstname + "</td>
                                                    <td>" + lastname + "</td>
                                                    <td>" + dob + "</td>
                                                    <td>" + email + "</td>
                                                    <td>" + phonenumber + "</td>
                                                </tr>";

          if(validateForm())
           {

             $("table tbody").append(markup);

           }
         });         
     });    


                                            </script>
                                        </body>
                                    </html>
```

Comment: Can you describe what issue are you getting and what should be done?

Comment: @JitendraRangpariya Actually when a user fills the form, on the button click, it must validate if all the fields are filled and then if all are filled by the user, it must append the filled details to the table that i displayed below

Comment: $('.form-group').each(function() validates the wrong element. You need to do $('.form-group input').each(function()

Comment: Thanks @Gerard but even then, it doesn't work., I gave a valid details, even then, the details are not getting inserted into tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the jQuery a little.

- value of input fields are validated
- form is no longer submitted when button is clicked on
- data is added to the table at the right place

```js
function validateForm() {
  var isValid = true;
  $('.form-group input').each(function() {
    //console.log($(this).val());
    if ($(this).val() === '')
      isValid = false;
  });
  return isValid;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".row").click(function() {
    var firstname = $("#fn").val();
    var lastname = $("#sn").val();
    var dob = $("#dob").val();
    var email = $("#em").val();
    var phonenumber = $("#phn").val();
    var markup = 
      "<tr><td>" + firstname + 
      "</td><td>" + lastname + 
      "</td><td >" + dob + 
      "</td><td>" + email + 
      "</td><td>" + phonenumber + 
      "</td></tr>";

    if (validateForm()) {
      $('.table tr:last').after(markup); /* Changed */
    }
    return false; /* Do not submit the form */
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 25px 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #6C220B;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Assignment on Javascript and Jquery:</h1>
  <h2>Details form :</h2>
  <form action="#" method="post" name="form">
    <div class="form-group" required>
      <label for="First Name">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fn" placeholder="Enter your first name" name="firstname" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Last Name">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sn" placeholder="Enter your last name" name="lastname" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Date of birth">Date of birth:</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dob" placeholder="Enter your date of birth" name="dateofbirth" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="em" placeholder="Enter your email id" name="email" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Phone Number">Phone Number:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phn" placeholder="Enter your phone number" name="phonenumber" required="">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="row" value="Click to Add Row">
  </form>
  <br>
  <h2>The table of data :</h2>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Date of birth</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Durai</td>
        <td>Saravanan</td>
        <td>16/01/1996</td>
        <td>durairaj1696@gmail.com</td>
        <td>9789879736</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit form web page is reload. If you stop this event your code starting work. Just add param in your form: `onsubmit="return false;"`

`<form action="#" method="post" name="form" onsubmit="return false;">{content}`

Answer (score 0):

You have added submit type button that why it will not adding form data to your table, If you change type as button so it will works,

`<input type="button" class="row" value="Click to Add Row">`

The required attribute works with only submit button so required validation you have to add manually from javascript.